# Combine two statements to one expression in MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to use the `SET x = IFNULL(expr1, expr2)` statements where I try to select an id in expr1 and if it doesn't exist, I want to insert a new row in expr2 and return the last inserted id with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`

How can I achive something like `SET x = IFNULL(SELECT id WHERE x = ..., (INSERT INTO ...; SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()))`? (expr2 seems to be a wrong syntax)

Comment: Are you trying to insert a row in a table only if it doesn't already exist? If so, you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: I started playing with this, but it's really unclear what you want. If you want uniqueness then get MySQL to enforce it by creating a UNIQUE index on the unique columns. If you're using a primary key then that will do. If you want `LAST_INSERT_ID()` then the column should be set to auto-increment too. This looks very much like an XY problem, so edit your quest to describe your use case accurately, and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly i think you want do something like this

```
DECLARE expr1 INT;
DECLARE returnValue INT;

SELECT id
FROM where-your-want
WHERE clause
INTO expr1;

IF expr1 IS NOT NULL THEN
   SELECT what-ever-you-want
   FROM where-you-want
   WHERE clause
   SET returnValue = -1;
ELSE
   INSERT INTO where-ever-you-want()
   VALUES ();
   SET returnValue = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END IF;

SELECT returnValue;
```

OF course all this code is part of stored procedure...